# MS SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Script to Write Query to Text file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query whose results I'd like to write to a text file.  I'm doing this across several Db's and output files and so would like to automate it.

I know how to do this in `SSMS` by running the script with the `output` set to `file` but was curious if there is a way to do it in a script.

Ideally something like :

```
SELECT * FROM tablel
OUTPUT TO 'c:\myFile1.txt'    

SELECT * FROM table2
OUTPUT TO 'c:\myFile2.txt'    

SELECT * FROM table3
OUTPUT TO 'c:\myFile3.txt'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you will output to the local server. Do you have access to it?

Comment: @njk: I'm using everything locally on my laptop.  OUTPUT is just a generic pseudocode way of representing what I'd like to do.

Comment: http://thiagsundar.wordpress.com/export-data-to-text-file/